# Export JSON to CSV in Parse Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, json, excel, csv

I've a have a template that have one button. This button export one current JSON to csv. The new excel shows the records of the previous JSON. I'm using the package http://papaparse.com/. The issue is the records of JSON like:

```
"publicaciones": [
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Information credibility on twitter",
            "authors": "C Castillo, M Mendoza, B Poblete",
            "info": "Proceedings of the 20th international conference on World wide web, 675-684, 2011",
            "citas": "811",
            "año": "2011"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Twitter Under Crisis: Can we trust what we RT?",
            "authors": "M Mendoza, B Poblete, C Castillo",
            "info": "Proceedings of the first workshop on social media analytics, 71-79, 2010",
            "citas": "607",
            "año": "2010"
        },....
```

The excel shows this [Object Object].

If anybody could help me. I'll I would be grateful.

tree.html

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn export">Export to CSV</button>
</div>
```

tree.js

```
"click .export":function(){
        var url_2 = window.location.pathname;
        var res_2 = url_2.split("/");
        var id_usuario_s_2 = res_2[2];
        var csvContent = CSV.unparse(Scrapers.find({id_usuario: id_usuario_s_2}).fetch());
        window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(csvContent), '_self');

      }
```

[image]

```
{
    "id_usuario": "6LYRTPEAAAAJ",
    "autor": "Marcelo Mendoza",
    "imagen_usuario": "/citations?view_op=view_photo&user=6LYRTPEAAAAJ&citpid=1",
    "institucion": "Universidad T�cnica Federico Santa Mar�a",
    "c_campos": 5,
    "campos": [
        "Web mining",
        "online social networks",
        "social media",
        "information retrieval",
        "sentiment analysis"
    ],
    "c_titulos": 20,
    "publicaciones": [
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Information credibility on twitter",
            "authors": "C Castillo, M Mendoza, B Poblete",
            "info": "Proceedings of the 20th international conference on World wide web, 675-684, 2011",
            "citas": "811",
            "año": "2011"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Twitter Under Crisis: Can we trust what we RT?",
            "authors": "M Mendoza, B Poblete, C Castillo",
            "info": "Proceedings of the first workshop on social media analytics, 71-79, 2010",
            "citas": "607",
            "año": "2010"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Query recommendation using query logs in search engines",
            "authors": "R Baeza-Yates, C Hurtado, M Mendoza",
            "info": "Current Trends in Database Technology-EDBT 2004 Workshops, 395-397, 2004",
            "citas": "597",
            "año": "2004"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Predicting information credibility in time-sensitive social media",
            "authors": "C Castillo, M Mendoza, B Poblete",
            "info": "Internet Research 23 (5), 560-588, 2013",
            "citas": "106",
            "año": "2013"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Do all birds tweet the same?: characterizing twitter around the world",
            "authors": "B Poblete, R Garcia, M Mendoza, A Jaimes",
            "info": "Proceedings of the 20th ACM international conference on Information and ..., 2011",
            "citas": "103",
            "año": "2011"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Modeling user search behavior",
            "authors": "R Baeza-Yates, C Hurtado, M Mendoza, G Dupret",
            "info": "Web Congress, 2005. LA-WEB 2005. Third Latin American, 10 pp., 2005",
            "citas": "96",
            "año": "2005"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Improving search engines by query clustering",
            "authors": "R Baeza‐Yates, C Hurtado, M Mendoza",
            "info": "Journal of the American Society for Information Science and Technology 58 ..., 2007",
            "citas": "70",
            "año": "2007"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Meta-level sentiment models for big social data analysis",
            "authors": "F Bravo-Marquez, M Mendoza, B Poblete",
            "info": "Knowledge-Based Systems 69, 86-99, 2014",
            "citas": "57",
            "año": "2014"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Combining strengths, emotions and polarities for boosting Twitter sentiment analysis",
            "authors": "F Bravo-Marquez, M Mendoza, B Poblete",
            "info": "Proceedings of the Second International Workshop on Issues of Sentiment ..., 2013",
            "citas": "57",
            "año": "2013"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Query clustering for boosting web page ranking",
            "authors": "R Baeza-Yates, C Hurtado, M Mendoza",
            "info": "International Atlantic Web Intelligence Conference, 164-175, 2004",
            "citas": "49",
            "año": "2004"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Automatic query recommendation using click-through data",
            "authors": "G Dupret, M Mendoza",
            "info": "Professional Practice in Artificial Intelligence, 303-312, 2006",
            "citas": "33",
            "año": "2006"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Recommending better queries from click-through data",
            "authors": "G Dupret, M Mendoza",
            "info": "International Symposium on String Processing and Information Retrieval, 41-44, 2005",
            "citas": "18",
            "año": "2005"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Opinion dynamics of elections in Twitter",
            "authors": "F Bravo-Marquez, D Gayo-Avello, M Mendoza, B Poblete",
            "info": "Web Congress (LA-WEB), 2012 Eighth Latin American, 32-39, 2012",
            "citas": "16",
            "año": "2012"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Identifying the intent of a user query using support vector machines",
            "authors": "M Mendoza, J Zamora",
            "info": "International Symposium on String Processing and Information Retrieval, 131-142, 2009",
            "citas": "16",
            "año": "2009"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "A web search analysis considering the intention behind queries",
            "authors": "M Mendoza, R Baeza-Yates",
            "info": "Latin American Web Conference, 2008. LA-WEB'08., 66-74, 2008",
            "citas": "16",
            "año": "2008"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "A statistical model of query log generation",
            "authors": "G Dupret, B Piwowarski, C Hurtado, M Mendoza",
            "info": "International Symposium on String Processing and Information Retrieval, 217-228, 2006",
            "citas": "13",
            "año": "2006"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Location cache for web queries",
            "authors": "M Marin, F Ferrarotti, M Mendoza, C Gomez-Pantoja, V Gil-Costa",
            "info": "Proceedings of the 18th ACM conference on Information and knowledge ..., 2009",
            "citas": "12",
            "año": "2009"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Distributed Ontology-Driven Focused Crawling",
            "authors": "R Campos, O Rojas, M Mar�n, M Mendoza",
            "info": "Parallel, Distributed and Network-Based Processing (PDP), 2013 21st ..., 2013",
            "citas": "10",
            "año": "2013"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Visual-semantic graphs: using queries to reduce the semantic gap in web image retrieval",
            "authors": "B Poblete, B Bustos, M Mendoza, JM Barrios",
            "info": "Proceedings of the 19th ACM international conference on Information and ..., 2010",
            "citas": "10",
            "año": "2010"
        },
        {
            "titulo_pub": "Building decision trees to identify the intent of a user query",
            "authors": "M Mendoza, J Zamora",
            "info": "Knowledge-Based and Intelligent Information and Engineering Systems, 285-292, 2009",
            "citas": "10",
            "año": "2009"
        }
    ],
    "c_coautores": 21,
    "coautores": [
        {
            "coautor_name": "Barbara Poblete",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=eZBFWGEAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Carlos Castillo",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=D4NJsXEIh1cJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Carlos Hurtado Larrain",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=SpM8IFkAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Ricardo Baeza-Yates",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=v9xULZwAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Georges Dupret",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=swZTxxcAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Felipe Bravo-Marquez",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=q--XWcQAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Mauricio Marin",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=t0-RzjEAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Alejandro Jaimes",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=-iy0DxMAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Juan Zamora",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=clXFk9YAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Miguel R. Guevara",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=n1qKMYwAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Mauricio Solar",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=dVZO4RgAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Dominik Hartmann",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=rM8qFkwAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Hernan Astudillo",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=32ekRVMAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Daniel Gayo-Avello",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=bdCROlQAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Gianmarco De Francisci Morales",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=R0JCEqMAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Veronica Gil-Costa",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=hwXEZ0IAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Cesar A. Hidalgo",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=xhCWdtMAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Benjamin Piwowarski",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=RP4lPE8AAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Carlos G�mez-Pantoja",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=SbBAYOkAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        },
        {
            "coautor_name": "Benjamin Bustos",
            "a_href": "https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=bbZWdFUAAAAJ&hl=es&oe=ASCII"
        }
    ],
    "citas_totales": "2826",
    "citas_2012": "2321",
    "indice_h_totales": "15",
    "indice_h_2012": "12",
    "indice_i10_totales": "20",
    "indice_i10_2012": "15"
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to get in place of these nested documents?

Comment: I hope the excel file shows all the records of the nested fields. It does not matter that other records are repeated. Something similar to this image, look at it please

Https://ibb.co/dL5SSF

Comment: In this case, the publications field has 5 nested fields. I expect something like the one shown in the picture above.

Any advice or help is welcome.

Comment: To get this result you should prepare your `JSON` first so it won't have nested documents. The parser itself won't do this for you.

Comment: Ok I understand. I'll see what I can do